# How can I convert an IDN to Punycode in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, idn

What is the easiest way to convert an IDN (such as президент.рф) to Punycode in bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [`idn`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libidn/manual/html_node/Invoking-idn.html):

```
[U] net-dns/libidn
     Available versions:  1.22 (~)1.22-r1 {doc elibc_FreeBSD emacs java mono nls static-libs}
     Installed versions:  1.22(03:12:19 PM 07/04/2011)(nls static-libs -doc -elibc_FreeBSD -emacs -java -mono)
     Homepage:            http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/
     Description:         Internationalized Domain Names (IDN) implementation
```

For e.g:

```
$ echo "президент.рф" | idn
xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai
```

Comment: In Ubuntu can be installed by `apt install idn`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have python on your system, `python -c 'import sys;print sys.argv[1].decode("utf-8").encode("idna")' "президент.рф"` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS `brew install homebrew/versions/libidn2`.

Then `echo "президент.рф" | idn2`.